# How can I prove that my parents can support me when I'm studying abroad?

Tags: tunisian-citizens

I am from Tunisia, I'm planning on my studying abroad next year. Every country I am interested in requires a certain amount of money when applying for visa or your parents' financial statement (if they work) from last several months. My dad is a cab driver and he doesn't have or use a bank account, my mom has few houses that she rents out.

How can I prove to the embassy that my parents don't have income that gets stated in a bank, but one of those houses' rent would be sent to me abroad every month to support me?

Comment: Open a bank account now and start depositing the house rent there. Many countries don't just want a month's money of support, they want the entire first year's amount available--you have to pay tuition upfront. Yes, this means that the family may need to start paying tax on this income if it's not already being paid.

Comment: You would need to show required funds in an account in a nationalized bank/institution. Decide on which country u want to study in, read their fund requirements and save accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to offer proof of your mother's ownership of the rental properties, along with their assessed value and copies of the rental contracts.  Perhaps you wouldn't need to present documentation of all of the houses. // If the rent was paid under the table last year, perhaps it would help you speed things up by declaring the 2017 rental income now (which would affect her tax situation for 2017), and drawing up some documentation of the rental arrangement after the fact.  A real estate attorney may be able to help with this without charging an arm and a leg.

Answer (score 11):

Converting comment to an answer as the comment was upvoted by several people.

Open a bank account now and start depositing the house rent there. Many countries don't just want a month's money of support, they want the entire first year's amount available--you have to pay tuition upfront. You might also have to pay housing fees upfront if living in university housing. Yes, this means that the family may need to start paying tax on this income if it's not already being paid.